# How to pass a nested struct into an argument

Tags: go, mux

I'm trying to create a struct for my API routes. I have two structs: Queries and Route. Then I have a slice of my routes that is made based of my type Route.

After I create my Routes, I then create a new router and iterate over the range of Routes and pass them Methods, Path, Handler, and Queries.

I keep getting an error when trying to pass queries that says

> cannot use route.Queries (type []Queries) as type string in argument...

```golang
type Queries struct {
    item     string
    useritem string
    key      string
    userkey  string
}


type Route struct {
    Method     string
    Path       string
    HandleFunc http.HandlerFunc
    Queries []Queries
}

var Routes = []Route{
    {
        Method:     "GET",
        Path:       "/items",
        HandleFunc: controllers.Getitems,
        Queries: []Queries{{"item", "{useritem}", "key", "{userkey}",},
        },
    },
}

func CreateRouter() *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    for _, route := range Routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Path).
            Handler(route.HandleFunc).
            Queries(route.Queries) //This is where the error occurs
        } 
        return router
    }
```

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. What is your question, or what do you specifically need help with?

Answer (score 1):

First convert `route.Queries` into `queries []string`.

Then you need to unpack array as arguments. Use `router.Queries(queries...)` instead.

See https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/mux.go#L341 for implementation of this method.

Comment: Thx for the response Michal. Can you help elaborate a little more. Where do I actually unpack the array?

Comment: @DevKiya note that the [`Queries`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Queries) method is *variadic*, which means that it can take *any* number of arguments of type `string`, this variadic nature of the method is indicated by the 3 dots (`...`) in front of the argument type, i.e. `...string`. So basically `...string` means any number of strings, just as `...int` means any number of ints, etc.

Comment: @DevKiya  To pass arguments to a variadic function you either have to list them explicitly, e.g. `router.Queries("item", "{useritem}", "key", "{userkey}")`, or you can collect them into a slice whose **element type** matches the **variadic type**, and then pass that slice to the variadic method *and* append 3 dots to the end of the slice value's name. So if the variadic type is `...string` then the slice type must be `[]string`, and then you can do something like this `args := []string{"item", "{useritem}", "key", "{userkey}"}` and `router.Queries(args...)`.

Comment: @mkopriva when passing them explicitly i get the following error:  `cannot call non-function route.Queries (type []Queries)go`

I want to explicitly state that arguments of the queries in the struct and pass them in my method of Queries(route.Queries) - im just not understanding how

Comment: @DevKiya `route.Queries` is not a function, that's your field, the function is `router.Queries`. route**r** not route.

Comment: @DevKiya anyway as i've already explained, you cannot pass `route.Queries` (type `[]Queries`) to a function that takes `...string`. Those are two different types, Go is a strongly typed language. It is simply not allowed.

Comment: @DevKiya as explained by Michał Krzysztof Feiler in his answer, you have to convert `route.Queries` (type `[]Queries`) into a value of type `[]string` and then pass that to `router.Queries` and adding those 3 dots.

Comment: ahh, i kept getting confused over route vs routes. Thanks!!

Comment: @mkopriva ive played with this for a while and have implemented (i think) the advise given above but am still getting an error. can you view the answer i posted?

Answer (score 0):

@mkopriva ive played with this for a while and have implemented (i think) the advise given above but now im getting `syntax error: unexpected ..., expecting expressiongo`

Here is what my code looks like now:

````golang
type Queries struct {
    item     string
    useritem string
    key      string
    userkey  string
}

type Route struct {
    Method     string
    Path       string
    HandleFunc http.HandlerFunc
    Queries []string
}


// Routes is
var Routes = []Route{
    {
        Method:     "GET",
        Path:       "/items",
        HandleFunc: controllers.Getitems,
        Queries: []string{
            "item", "{useritem}", "key", "{userkey}",
        },
    },
}

// CreateRouter is
func CreateRouter() {

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    for _, route := range Routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Path).
            Handler(route.HandleFunc).
            Queries(router.Queries(...))
    }
    return router
}```
````

Comment: Change `Queries(router.Queries(...))` to `Queries(route.Queries...)`

Comment: note again you're mixing up `router` with `route`, if you find the names confusing then use different variable names.

Comment: thanks so much! that worked. appreciate your time, im v new to go